# How to access session variables from a Draper decorator in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables, decorator, instantiation, draper

I want to be able to access a session variable from the Decorator. Now I can't do so, nor can I access controller instance variables, let's say `@session_variable`.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the idea is that decoraters should be an extension of the model it decorates. Because of that it gets complicated. I would take the session variable as an input parameter to the decorater function.

Answer (score 0):

When I need any object other than a controller to have access to request information, I like to use what I think of as the Context pattern. It looks like this:

Write a singleton class that has only the interface that your decorator needs (following the Interface Segregation Principle). As an example, let's say that your decorator needs to know whether the user is logged in. Make a `LoginContext` singleton with an instance method `user_is_logged_in?`. The decorator can find out whether a the user is logged in by calling `LoginContext.instance.user_is_logged_in?`.

Add an `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController` that sets the singleton's `user_is_logged_in` attribute to `true` or `false` according to the session before running the action. Optionally, if you want to make sure that nothing uses the `LoginContext` outside of a request, make the filter an `around_filter` and set the attribute to `nil` after running the action, and write the `user_is_logged_in?` accessor so that it raises an error if the attribute is nil.

The above is for single-threaded Rails application servers, but you can write the same functionality around a thread-specific singleton if you use a threaded application server.